# Confused about getting weird characters after using qsort() in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting

I am learning to use C's qsort() to sort an array of characters, `char s[]="atlantic"`.  After qsort() is returned, I print out my `s`, but I got only unreadable characters. I think my compare() is correct since all qsort() needs is to use it to find out whether *a is before/equal/after *b.  Does anyone have an idea what cause the line `printf("After: %s\n", s);` not work?  Thanks.

```
int compare(const void * a, const void * b){
  return *(char*)a - *(char*)b;
}
void doWork(char* s) {
  printf("Before: %s\n", s);
  qsort(s, strlen(s), sizeof(char *), compare);
  printf("After: %s\n", s); 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
qsort(s, strlen(s), sizeof(char *), compare);
```

You appear to be telling `qsort` here that the type you're sorting is a `char*` rather than a `char`. Unless your pointers are exactly the same size as your characters, that's not going to end well :-)

You should be using:

```
qsort(s, strlen(s), sizeof(char), compare);
```

or, since `sizeof(char)` is *always* `1`, you can get away with:

```
qsort(s, strlen(s), 1, compare);
```

Although, in the interests of minimising code changes should you need to change the type in future, you can use the variable rather than the type directly:

```
qsort(s, strlen(s), sizeof(*s), compare);
```

---

With any of those changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare(const void * a, const void * b){
    return *(char*)a - *(char*)b;
}

void doWork(char* s) {
    printf("Before: %s\n", s);
    qsort(s, strlen(s), sizeof(*s), compare);
    printf("After:  %s\n", s);
}

int main (void) {
    char s[] = "atlantic";
    doWork(s);
    return 0;
}
```

you'll see the output you're looking for:

```
Before: atlantic
After:  aacilntt
```

Comment: `sizeof *s` would be another option  , possibly useful if the code is later adapted for `wchar_t` strings

Answer (score 2):

The elements of `s` are not type `char *` so they don't have `sizeof (char *)`, use `sizeof (char)` instead.

```
qsort(s, strlen(s), sizeof(char), compare);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are passing `sizeof(char*)` to `qsort` where `sizeof(char)` is appropriate.

Use

```
qsort(s, strlen(s), sizeof(char), compare);
```